# jq - Get a higher level key after a selection

Tags: json, select, key, jq

Given a JSON like the following:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": "1a2b3c",
    "info": {
      "a": {
        "number": 0
      },
      "b": {
        "number": 1
      },
      "c": {
        "number": 2
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

I want to select on a number that is greater than or equal to 2 and for that selection I want to return the values of `id` and `number`. I did this like so:

```
$ jq -r '.data[] | .id as $ID | .info[] | select(.number >= 2) | [$ID, .number]' in.json
[
  "1a2b3c",
  2
]
```

Now I would also like to return a higher level key for my selection, in my case I need to return `c`. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the string `"c"` instead of `2` in the output, this will work:

```sh
$ jq '.data[] | .id as $ID | .info | to_entries[] | select(.value.number >= 2) | [$ID, .key]' input.json
[
  "1a2b3c",
  "c"
]
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! For completeness, adding the number gave me the exact output I needed; `[$ID, .key, .value.number]`